# A sentence riddle breakdown

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Solve the separate riddles to complete the sentence.

1.

> Listen in, to half the score
>   
> Pick back up off the floor

2.

> One in the pod, set up a vote
>   
> Human beings in the same boat

3.

> Take action, then boycott
>   
> Yes and no in a knot

4.

> Replace, what is scheduled now
>   
> Instead you put people down

> What is the sentence?

Hint:

> Each word is made up of two parts, both described in the first line (kinda like compound words). The second line is the definition of the word

Comment: The first riddle, is it supposed to be "of" or "off"?

Comment: first word could be 'hearten', but that's all I can get so far

Comment: I kind of feel like #2 is some sort of phrase with pea and sea.

Comment: @LiamH that's the first bit right

Comment: @Raystafarian the 'pea' bit is right, the next bit is another name for vote

Comment: It must be soylent green!

Comment: Pea Poll = People right?

Comment: YES! @gannolloy you got it!

Comment: All of the words are similar to that made up of two parts - see the hint

Comment: 4. could be subdue?

Comment: @gannolloy you've got enough for a partial answer now. You've got the hang of it! that's 3 done, just no. 3 left

Comment: Are there any filler words like and, the, etc.

Comment: @gannolloy no there aren't, three is probably the trickiest - the riddle is a bit tenuous but you could probably almost guess it from the sentence considering its the last word

Comment: So far we have HEARTEN PEOPLE, ... SUBDUE

Comment: @gannolloy soylent green *is* people!

Comment: @Raystafarian oh right, I thought you meant the words were literally soylent green

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess:

> Hearten People Don't Subdue

Listen in, to half the score

Pick back up off the floor

> Hearten (Hear and Ten)

One in the pod, set up a vote

Human beings in the same boat

> People (Pea Poll)

Take action, then boycott

Yes and no in a knot

> Don't (Do and Not)

Replace, what is scheduled now

Instead you put people down

> Subdue (Substitute and Due)

Comment: Well done, spot on

Comment: This is supposed to be a sentence??

Comment: @f'' Maaaayyybe with a comma (or semicolon) between the two halves?